# Visual studio code 2019 and protobuf cpp code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, grpc, protobuf-c

I want to run the grpc in visual studio without cmake. I followed these steps:

- create New project in VIsual Studio 2019
- I added helloWorld.proto file in proto folder
- created by pb.cc and pb.h, and grpc.pb.cc and grpc.h through protoc and grpc_cpp_plugin

Now I added pb.cc and grpc.cc in source file and added pb,h and grpc.h in header file.

In visual studio C/c++ directories , added the path in include directories

```
 vcpkg\packages\grpc_x64-windows\include
 vcpkg\packages\grpc_x64-windows\lib
 vcpkg\packages\protobuf_x64-windows\include
 vcpkg\packages\protobuf_x64-windows\lib
```

- preprocessor added WIN32
- Linker : additional library Directories: vcpkg\packages\protobuf_x64-windows\debug
- Linker - Input - added following [enter link description here][1]

  libprotoc.lib
  libprotobuf-lite.lib
  libprotobufd.lib
  grpc.lib
  grpc++.lib
  gpr.lib
  cares.lib
  WS2_32.lib

I am getting error

> error C2660: 'google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors': function does not take 3 arguments

can anyone suggest me the solution for the same or basic steps to create grpc structure in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please revise how to format questions properly. I've fixed most of it for you.